# Exporting sheet using only values(not formulas)

Tags: vba, excel

I am working to export one of the sheet in a workbook.With the following code i was able to do that.However the sheet i am trying to export uses formulas to retrive data in other sheets in workbook.When i change values in main workbook,exported workbook also changes.How can i export the sheet using only values?

```
Private Sub SAVE()
On Error Resume Next
location = Sheets("data").Range("j2").text
date= Application.text(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        Ad = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Ad & location & date ".xlsm",FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ad this piece of code after the `ActiveSheet.Copy`

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
```

This will work so long as there are no merged cells in your sheets.

As a side note, the variable `Ad` is not necessary to save the workbook. As long as `location` is valid file path, the `FileName:=location & date & ".xlsm"` will work.

Comment: Thank you so much.This worked even on merged cells on exported sheet?.I wil try save it without ad variable.